# Make Python 3.6+ Code in Compatible with Python 3.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, python-3.6

Here is a part of code ([Parso](https://github.com/davidhalter/parso/)) in Python 3.6:

```
class BaseParser:
"""Parser engine.
A Parser instance contains state pertaining to the current token
sequence, and should not be used concurrently by different threads
to parse separate token sequences.
See python/tokenize.py for how to get input tokens by a string.
When a syntax error occurs, error_recovery() is called.
"""

node_map: Dict[str, type] = {}
default_node = tree.Node

leaf_map: Dict[str, type] = {}
default_leaf = tree.Leaf

def __init__(self, pgen_grammar, start_nonterminal='file_input', error_recovery=False):
    self._pgen_grammar = pgen_grammar
    self._start_nonterminal = start_nonterminal
    self._error_recovery = error_recovery
```

How can I make it compatible with Python 3.3?
What is the usage of `leaf_map: Dict[str, type] = {}`? Can I remove it?

Comment: Seriously, why? Python 3.3 is dead for years now.

Comment: Unfortunately, the environment that I should run my code supports only p3.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Dict[str, type]` is python type annotations. It has no impact in runtime and can be removed.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html

Comment: Why don't you read the documentation? If you don't need `typing` anymore then don't install it.